# cordova + ionic + crosswalk = net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk

I'm building a `cordova/ionic app`, on my **phone (android 6.0.1)** works fine, like in `chrome (desktop)`, a few days ago I add crosswalk to get best functionality when I use my **old phone (android 4.4.1)**, but, all requests gets the **same error**.

> GET
>   https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/firebase-wodfit.appspot.com/o/i…e_user%2Fno-photo.jpg?alt=media&token=795a805a-af52-4d56-95e7-112a5ba6157d
>   **net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE**

I try to configure the whitelist plugin in **config.xml** like:

```
  <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

or the **content security**:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' ; img-src 'self' data: *;">
```

this is my system information

**> ionic info**

```
Your system information:
 ordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.9.1
Xcode version: Not installed
```

**some cordova's plugin:**

```
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.3.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
```

**> cordova platform version**

```
Installed platforms:
  android 6.1.2
```

**NOTE:** If I remove crosswalk there is no error running on **android 4.4.1**, but the user experience is just terrible, Using crosswalk the app works perfect, but offline, because of that error.

Comment: Were you able to find any solution?

Comment: yes, I removed everything and start from scratch